# Handling "Dropdown does not contain selected item" Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am having trouble with a particular situation. The values in my `dropdownlist` are as follows: `101, 102, 103`, but at any point in time the use can add or deactivate items to the dropdown ex: `101, 104, 106`.

I have this `dropdownlist` embedded into a listview edit item template. So if the user adds a record with value `102`, then later on deletes this value they cannot edit this value because I get the above error.

So what I am trying to figure out is how I can handle this message to let the use know they cannot edit the record. What I have so far is the `ListView_ItemEditing` event handler:

```
protected void LV_Equipment_ItemEditing(object sender, ListViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    LV_Equipment.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    e.Cancel = true;

    try
    {
        LV_Equipment.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //This is telling the user they cannot edit the record.
        AlertMessage("you cannot edit this record.");
    }

    DropDownList UnitIDDDL = (DropDownList)(LV_Equipment.EditItem.FindControl("DropDownList1"));
    DropDownList DriverIDDDL = (DropDownList)(LV_Equipment.EditItem.FindControl("DDL_Insert_Drivers"));

    //We need to get the driver for the selected unit in the listview.
    int ID = DatabaseInteraction.GetUnitDriver(UnitIDDDL.SelectedValue);

    //Now that we have the id we can set the ddl.
    DriverIDDDL.SelectedValue = ID.ToString();
    DriverIDDDL.DataBind();
}
```

So if the user tries to edit a valid item there is no problem. But if they try to edit a deactivated item from the listview they `LV_Equipment.DataBind()` method will fail, and the rest of the code will throw an error as the `UnitIDDDL` and `DriverIDDDL` are set as null.

Any ideas on how to make this workaround effective?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what you need to do.

Your data binding should be coming from a SQL query of some sort. Let's assume it looks something like this:

```
string query = "SELECT ItemNumber FROM TableName";
SqlConnection conn;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query,conn);
DataTable sqlTable = new DataTable("Test"); 
da.Fill(sqlTable);
LV_Equipment.DataSource = sqlTable;
```

What you'll want to do is change your query so that it looks something like this:
    string query  = "SELECT  ItemNumber FROM TableName WHERE Active = 'True'";

That should solve your problem.

<strike>Add a return to your catch block:</strike>

```
try
{
    LV_Equipment.DataBind();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //This is telling the user they cannot edit the record.
    AlertMessage("you cannot edit this record.");
    return; // don't continue to process
}
```

Comment: I tried this earlier, but when I do this the ListView in the asp code throws an error of trying to databind.

Comment: Ahh - maybe in the catch block then, set the EditIndex to one you know exists?  i.e. LV_Equipment.EditIndex = 0

Comment: Yes, but if the DataBind() fails, then the dropdowns are set to null, so you cannot set their index.

Comment: Is there something preventing you from just removing the value fromt he list when the user deletes it?

Comment: Well that is currently what I am doing. If the user deactivates the item, I remove it from the dropdownlist.

But since there are historical records inside the database that contain that item, they can be eidtted which cause this problem.

Comment: Modify your data binding so that it excludes inactive items - if there isn't a column for this in the database, make one.

Comment: How would I modify the databind to do so? I have a column in the database that is `Active`, and when a user deletes the item it just sets that to "No".